# Blank photo on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook API to upload an image and then attach it to a post.

I am passing a url and no story = true which successfully returns an ID.

I then attach it to my post using object_attachment which works fine. But when I view the post I don't see the image I just see the text, but if I click the image then it works fine - I see the full size album entry.

If I choose no story = false then the image does appear in the feed but still doesn't attach - thus I doubt its permissions because with no story false it works fine.

Any thoughts

Thanks

Antony